# Integral representation $f(x) = \lim_{n = \infty} \sum_1^n \ln(n)^2 + n \ln(x)^2 - \sum_1^n \ln(x+n)^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

Let $x>1$ be a real variable.

$$f(x) = \lim_{n = \infty} \sum_1^n \ln(n)^2 + n \ln(x)^2 - \sum_1^n \ln(x+n)^2$$

Is there an integral representation for $f(x)$ that uses no $\sum$ , named polynomials nor non-analytic functions ?
( so no " cheap" Floor function or Sum in the integrand )

Notice that the analogue limit above with $\ln^2$ replaced by $\ln$ gives us the lngamma and various integral representations such as

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MalmstensFormula.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html

Comment: $n$ is the summation variable and also the upper limit. $n=\infty$ typo.

Comment: Yeah a bit notation abuse. Sorry.

Comment: David Hill removed the representation tag. I think someone should create the integral representation tag.

Answer (score 2):

By [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula):

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^2(k) &=& n\log^2(n)-\int_{1}^{n}\lfloor x\rfloor \frac{2\log(x)}{x}\,dx\\ &=& n\log^2(n)-2n\log(n)+2n-2+\int_{1}^{n}2\frac{\{x\}}{x}\log(x)\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the last integral is clearly bounded by $\log^2(n)$. In order to achieve further precision, one may expand $\frac{1}{2}-\{x\}$ as a Fourier sine series then use integration by parts. We may notice that
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}(2\{x\}-1)\frac{\log x}{x}\,dx $$
is a convergent integral by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), since $(2\{x\}-1)$ has a bounded primitive (a multiple of $\text{Re}\left(\text{Li}_2(e^{-2\pi i x})\right)$) while $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is decreasing to zero on $(e,+\infty)$. That gives:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^2(k) = \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log^2(n)-2n\log(n)+2n+O(1)$$

also without finding an explicit integral representation.

The limit can be found by noticing that:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\log^2(k)-\log^2(x+k)\right) &=& -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k}^{k+x}\frac{2\log t}{t}\,dt\\ &=& 2\left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_{0}^{x}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{dt}{(t+k)^{\alpha}}\right|_{\alpha=1^+}\\&=&2\left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_{0}^{x}\zeta(\alpha,t+1)\,dt\,\right|_{\alpha=1^+}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $\zeta(\alpha,t+1)$ is a [Hurwitz zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html).

Comment: Any particular reason why u use Abel summation? I'm asking because Euler Mac Laurin seems to be more straightforward here (no needs for Fourier series for example)

Comment: @tired: no particular reason, they are quite equivalent in this case, we just have to reach $2\{x\}-1$ and notice it has a bounded primitive.

Comment: Ok, nice solution anyway (+1)

Comment: Kinda Nice. But no integral representation. Im not sure if it Will even help considering you give a good estimate , but An integral representation is exact. I was aware of Abel's formula but did not mention it, since im not sure how it helps. Thanks for the effort though. But I can not accept it as you can understand. You answered a different question. I had the idea that no representation exists but that would require proof.

Comment: @mick: actually I found an integral representation, but it involves Hurwitz zeta function. Please see my updated answer.